# How to get the Elements defined under Control Template in runtime in WPF

Tags: wpf

How to get the Elements defined under Control Template in runtime in WPF

Answer (score 2):

use the Template Properties FindName method

*Control*.Template.FindName

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the VisualTreeHelper to find children. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement); i++)
{
    var childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
    // Do something with object here
}
```

Comment: This works if you invoke `parentElement.ApplyTemplate()`, otherwise, it may return no child.